# How can i get unread mails in E-Mail inboxes By POP3 Using PHP

Tags: php

im trying to get my unread messages in my e-mail inbox , i tried with impat but didn't work , if you have any idea about it please let me know.

```
<?php

function mailCount($host, $login, $passwd)
{
    $mbox = imap_open($host, $login, $passwd);
    $mail = '';

    if($mail = imap_check($mbox))
    {
        return $mail->Nmsgs;
    }
}

$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$count = mailCount($hostname, $username, $password);
?>
```

i tried with this code but i still have no results , i need help with some examples.

Comment: This code uses IMAP not POP3

Comment: "Didn't work" is a meaningless statement. Explain what you are seeing - is there an error? Some unexpected behaviour? Be specific. See also [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using POP3 to fetch unread emails using PHP. Note that the POP3 protocol doesn't inherently support the "unread" status as IMAP does, so once an email is fetched via POP3, it's usually marked as read on the server. If you want to fetch only unread messages and maintain their unread status, IMAP is generally a better choice.

That being said, if you still want to proceed with POP3, here's how you can achieve it using PHP:

1. Install the required extension if not already available.

```bash
composer require ddeboer/imap
```

2. Use the following code to fetch unread emails using POP3:

```php
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

function getUnreadMails($host, $port, $username, $password)
{
    $server = new \Ddeboer\Imap\Server($host, $port);
    $connection = $server->authenticate($username, $password);

    // Fetch unread mails
    $mailbox = $connection->getMailbox('INBOX');
    $messages = $mailbox->getMessages(\Ddeboer\Imap\SearchExpression::unseen());

    return $messages;
}

$host = 'pop.gmail.com';
$port = 995; // POP3 over SSL
$username = 'username@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';

$unreadMessages = getUnreadMails($host, $port, $username, $password);
echo "You have " . count($unreadMessages) . " unread messages.\n";

?>
```

Note:

- You would need to adjust the username and password accordingly.
- Ensure you've enabled "Allow less secure apps" in your Gmail settings for this to work. However, it's generally advised to use OAuth2 for better security.
- It's always better to use IMAP for this kind of operation if you wish to maintain the unread status of emails on the server.